# ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED files and folders

Tags: lubuntu, encryption, ext4

I had a problem using my old hard drive, so I'm willing to recover the files in it, but it is encrypted, and all the files and folders are named ENCRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED and some gibbberish...

The question is: how do I recover all this files and unencrypt them?
Thank you for your time and your effort.

I am using Lubuntu 14.10 and Lubuntu 14.04 is installed in the old hard drive.
The old one (encrypted) is ext4, the new one (non-encrypted) is FAT.

Problem solved thanks to Xen2050.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `ecryptfs-recover-private` might work for you, it's supposed to search all drives for encrypted private folders and let you decrypt/read them, or you tell it which private folder to try. May work best when ran from a live cd/usb, maybe try that if it doesn't work.

Comment: No problem, hope I get an accepted/check marked answer (hint ;-)   And for the future, don't forget the golden rule of data, especially important with encryption, **MAKE BACKUPS!** One day the key could get lost, or a critical LUKS block could get corrupted, and then the data's lost for 100 or 1000 years, (depending on your computer speed & luck)